# Стиль программирования

Tags: code-style

Довольно часто встречаю чужой код, и возник вопрос:
Почему, с какой целью и откуда пошёл такой стиль:

```
if ( a == b )
{
  op1
  op2
  op3
}
```

В противовес:

```
if ( a == b ) {
  op1
  op2
  op3
}
```

Что хочет донести программист переносом строки перед **{**? ( возможно мне одному не ясно )

Comment: А какой у Вас стиль?

Comment: Такой:

    if ( a== b ) { 
    }
    else {
    }

Comment: И я. Вообще-то он рекомендуется для кода ядра разных никсов.

Comment: Да по-моему, это все как в истории про тупоконечных и остроконечных. Кто как привык. Разницы большой я не вижу.

Comment: Зачем делают отступы? - Для структурного деления кода ( python - яркий пример )<br>
Зачем делают данный перенос???<br>
P.S. Возможно ищу смысл там где его нет...

Comment: собственно не так давно начал переносить { в новую строку, честно говоря понравилось) теперь в php, js ипользую перенос. странно что css пока что пишу таким вот образом

`#div { style properties; }` т.е. стилизация каждого элемента все в одну строку.

Comment: Интересно а что с вашей точки зрения более читабельно?
    If a=b then begin
     Do1
     do2
    end;

или таки
    If (a=b) then
    Begin
     do1 
     do2
    end;

Comment: если вы не можете понять смысл переноса { на новую строку, то объясните нам почему вы переносите } на новую, а { не переносите?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я думаю, стиль программирования с переносом фигурной скобки мог прийти из старой формы определения функций в С:

```
int function (a, b) 
int a;
int b;
{
...
}
```

Comment: Один из немногих ответов по теме)

Answer (score 7):

Чисто визуально этот код

```
If (a == b)
{

}
```

выглядит лучше, чем

```
If (a == b) {

}
```

Несмотря на то, что так экономится лишнее место читать код в первом случае приятнее. Можно конечно засунуть всё в одну строку, так компактно, но главное – это читабельность и, возможно, красота кода. Стиль чисто интуитивный.

Comment: вот уж "Выглядит лучше" - очень спорно)

Comment: Просто лишняя скобка наряду с условием не совсем к месту. Всё время возникает желание опустить её на строчку ниже.

Comment: Так чисто визуально блоки лучше выделяются на фоне остального кода, удобно. Да и просто эстетичнее.

Comment: Красиво, удобно, эстетично - это не корректные критерии оценки.

Comment: Ну, стиль программирования - для программиста, а не для компилятора=)

Comment: Если вы так делаете, то что вам побудило **первоначально** сделать так:
1. Мне сказал преподаватель
2. Я провёл исследование и заметил, что выбросы CO2 от этого меньше;)
3. Компилятор только так компилировал
 и .....

Не думаю, что когда вы начинали, вы задумывались о красивости, и проводили замеры красивометром что лучше... Просто привычка - и это нормально... Вот только вопрос о другом....

Comment: Особо порадовало про СО2. Родная тема.

Answer (score 4):

Прихожанин: Ребе, зачем надо делать обрезание?

Ребе (после раздумий): Ну, во-первых, это красиво...

А вот у Свифтовских лилипутов были две антагонистические партии. Одни предлагали бить вареные яйца с тупого конца, зато другие настаивали, чтобы - с острого.

Comment: Да вообще, веселый бла-бла ни о чем

Comment: Цель есть - понять то, что не ясно)

Comment: Да тут нельзя ничего понять. Это дело в основном не логики, а эстетического вкуса.

Answer (score 4):

Имхо, во всем должен быть здравый смысл.

Важно чтобы на один листинг экрана вмещалось как можно больше кода, и не страдала читабельность.

Если и условие простое, и решение по этому условию, то:

```
if( a == b ) new Exception('Такого не может быть!');
```

Если условие простое, а решение сложное, то:

```
if( a == b ){
    // 1-я строка
    // 2-я строка
    // ...
    // n-я строка
}
```

Если нужны сложные конструкции в обоих блоках, то:

```
if(
    (длинное_название_переменной_1  == длинное_название_переменной_2) && (
        (длинное_название_переменной_3  == длинное_название_переменной_4) ||
        (длинное_название_переменной_5  == длинное_название_переменной_6) ||
        // ... и еще куча всего ...
    )
){
    // 1-я строка
    // 2-я строка
    // ...
    // n-я строка
}
```

Все это особенно остро ощущается в верстке SQL-запросов со сложной логикой.

Answer (score 3):

я ореинтируюсь в коде именно по `{...}`, поэтому мне перенос просто необходим, когда не вижу под `` if`ом ``(или другим оператором) фигурной скобки у меня интуитивно возникает мысль, что он действует только на *следующие* выражение

Плюс ко всему бегать глазами так:

```
V
----> {
      V Some Code;
      V Some Code;
      V Some Code;
}<----
V
```

сложнее чем так:

```
V
{
V    Some Code;
V    Some Code;
V    Some Code;
}
V
```

Comment: Много времени ушло на осознавание вашего **V**.... <br>
Не очень ясно почему вы ориентируетесь по фигурным скобкам, т.к. для этого предназначены отступы....

Ибо в таком случае, ваша логика не применима:


    if ( a ==b )... к примеру 40 символов на условие
        ....к примеру 40 символов на операцию

Comment: я описал только свои ощущения, т.к. так мне удобней, с этой целью я делаю перенос скобки

Answer (score 1):

Да, 1 скобку, я считаю, нужно на первой строке писать. А стиль такой из-за вложенности условий. И компиляторы, например, Visual Studio подсвечивают при нажатии на одну из скобок парную скобку и её более видно если все скобки стоят первыми в строке., т.е.:

```
if(a==b)
{
  if(a==c)
  {
    if(a==c)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

И согласитесь так красивее и удобнее) Чем если действовать по-другому:

```
if(a==b){
  k = a*5+b;
  if(a==c){
    k += c;
    if(a==x){
      k +=x*a*c
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: не умею, я просто заключаю в &lt;code> Расскажи как?

Comment: Не соглашусь. Все мои знакомые (кроме одного) пишут

    if (...) {
        xaxa();
    } else {
        xoxo();
    }

Возможно это пошло от терминалов с 24 строками (больше кода на экране, а структура замечательно видна).

Но, в любом случае, это все дурацкий холивар.

Comment: @mctrane, сделал форматирование вашего ответа<br>
P.S: Если экономить на пробелах - то читать сложно в любом случае...

    if ( a == b ) {
      k = a * 5 + b;
      if ( a == c ) {
        k += c;
        if ( a == x ) {
          k += x * a * c
        }
      }
    }

Answer (score 1):

зависит он языка программирования и самого программиста, например, стиль как в примере - так автокорректирует студия, ну или есть прогеры, которые предпочитают переменные начинать с _, ну а в яве - там можно устанавливать самому один из многих стилей

Comment: не знаю как в VS, но Resharper тоже можно настроить под разные методы форматирования разных оператором

Comment: удобство каждый выбирайет сам) главное что на работу кода это никак не влияет)

Comment: а на работу программиста, который этот код читает?

Comment: влияет на работу в команде, надо что бы все придерживались одного, что бы когда ты берешь чужой код, ты этого не замечал, а мог без задержек продолжать его допиливать или править

Comment: Когда пишет команда, то конечно, должен быть один стиль. И надо на корню пресечь все разговоры, кому что удобнее. Один и все. А когда пишешь для себя, можно писать как тебе удобнее.

Comment: Я видел такое на разных языках и почти у всех новичков ( так-же как и отсутствие отступов )<br>
ИМХО - язык врятли имеет влияние

Comment: По моему это декларация о намерениях. Ни разу не встречал команду в которой к кому-нибудь из-за расстановки скобочек санкции применили.

Comment: И это напрасно. Сразу премии лишать. )))

Comment: @Gorets, Qt тоже так делает<br>
Вопрос ЗАЧЕМ так делать? Какие плюсы от переноса скобочки?

Comment: Да нет тут ни плюсов, ни минусов. Пора тему закрывать.

Comment: холивар, тролли подкрепились ))

Comment: это тоже самое, что спорить как писать ``ClassName`` или ``className``, ``MethodName`` или ``methodName``, ``privateField`` или ``_privateField``

Comment: В javascript надо писать так(связано с автоматической подстановкой **;**):

    function() {
    
    }

В остальных языках - как нравится так и пишите :)

PS:сам пишу так-же как и ТС
PPS:раньше писал подругому, при работе с большими кодами мне так намного удобнее
PPPS:это все, на самом деле - не важно :)

Answer (score 1):

Каждому программисту свой стиль - кому-то одно больше удобно, кому-то другое... это если делать один проект на много человек, да там нужен определенный стиль чтобы другие могли легко ориентироваться в коде... Я например пишу так чтобы всем было понятно и сам код выглядел красиво. Пример

```
if(a == b)
{
a++;
}
else
{
b++;
}
```

Ведь это намного красивее чем :

```
if(a == b){
a++;
} else {
b++;
}
```

Comment: У вас нет форматирования, сравнение не корректо

Comment: Я просто привел пример, уже то что между скобками, автор сможет свой код вставить.

Comment: Имеется в виду, что за такой код ( без отступов ) - вас почти все съедят)

Comment: Вы так пишите код?О_О

Без пробелов чтоле? xDDDDD

Answer (score 1):

Ответом на вопрос будет то, что люди редко интересуются (или читают) некоторыми(е) рекомендациями(ии) к тому, что делать надо, а чего не стоит. Отсюда привыкают работать так, а не иначе, создавая последователям, если они есть, трудности в освоении их кода.

Например, есть множество рекомендаций к тому, как писать и правильно оформлять свой код на том или ином языке программирования. Например, приведу [рекомендации](http://www.cs.bilgi.edu.tr/pages/standards_project/java_CodingStyle.pdf) одного из сотрудников Sun для Java кода.

Вот что он пишет:

> The importance and benefits of a
> consistent coding style are well
> known. This document describes a set
> of coding standards and
> recommendations for programs written
> in the Java language. It is intended
> for all Java software developers. It
> contains no material proprietary to
> Sun, and may be freely distributed
> outside Sun as well.
>
> The importance and benefits of a
> consistent coding style are well
> known. A consistent style:
>
> 1. improves the readability, and therefore, maintainability of code
> 2. facilitates sharing of code among different programmers, especially
>    teams of programmers working on the
>    same project.
> 3. allows easier development of automated tools to assist in program
>    development, such as tools which
>    automatically format or pretty-print
>    source code.
> 4. makes it easier to conduct code reviews, another software engineering
>    process with well-known benefits. In
>    turn, a practice of regular code
>    reviews can help enforce a consistent
>    style.
> 5. saves development time, once the guidelines are learned, by allowing
>    programmers to focus on the semantics
>    of the code, rather than spend time
>    trying to determine what particular
>    format is appropriate for a given
>    situation.

Мало кто задумывается, что такое читаемый код потому, что каждый пишет как хочет. Каждый треплется на тему, как же плохо пишут другие и насколько программа не читабельна, а по сути сами никогда ни о ком не думают кроме себя, когда пишут свой код. Вот и получаются холивары в итоге. Единственное, что всех спасает - данные документы являются исключительно рекомендательными.

---

**Невероятная истина**: польза от подобного форматирования - увеличение цены от количества строк кода. Думаю из тех краёв, Китай, Индия и иже с ними сие могло прийти (**юмор**).

Comment: вот это:

    if(false)
    {
        //пара сотен строк кода
    }

выгода от кол-ва строк кода, а форматирование - это мелочи

Comment: Если между скобками лежит пара сотен строчек кода, это яркий пример очень плохого стиля.

Comment: а то, что эти строки никогда не выполнятся вас не смущает?

Comment: @Spectre, это и все, что вы заметили в моем ответе?

Answer (score 1):

Ну уж и я допишу) Мне как-то прижилось вот такое.

Как минимум позволяет визуально легко смотреть уровни вложенности.

```
function f1(a, b) {
  if (a == 0) {
    a *= f12() + f15(a);
    b = f2(1, b);
    if (b > 15) {
      f4(a);
      f5(b)
      }
    if (a > 17) 
      f86(a);
    return f6(a, b);
    }
  return f7(a, b);
  }
```

Мне оно кажется более удобным для чтения, ибо за сдвиг глаза цепляются быстрее, чем за "{". Тем более в дельфях их, например, вообще нет)

*Таки да, совсем имхо.*

Comment: )) А по какой причине отступ перед **}**?)

Comment: каждый из 10 ответов говорит, что всё это дело исключительно личных предпочтений
P.S. долго не мог понять к чему относится предпоследняя **}**

Comment: @timka_s, если честно, не знаю) Но по логике функция - тоже "как бы вложенность в программе" =)

JS:

    var a = {
      b: function() {
        this.f = function() {
          return g;
          }
        return c;
        },
      d: 5,
      e: 15
      }

Здесь бы закрывающая встала в ряд с d и e.

Comment: Всегда писал)):

    var a = {
      b: function() {
        this.f = function() {
          return g;
        }
        return c;
      },
      d: 5,
      e: 15
    }

Comment: Ну вот я по привычке вижу у объекта свойства "b", "}", "d" и "e" ))

Comment: А теперь, давайте честно, кто работает в команде с многочисленным реюзом кода? У кого есть в команде люди, занимающиеся документированием?

Comment: Честно - не я и не у меня)

Comment: Ни в одной не было выделенных сотрудников (про документацию кода и его групповые инспекции).

Comment: @Sh4dow, вот поэтому вы и можете себе позволить такие вольности. А иначе бы мозг жрали вам ежедневно.

Comment: @Dex, вы путаете причину и следствие ;) Ну и если бы хоть кто-то, чье мнение мне важно, жаловался на мой код, я бы задумался, а пока я молча плююсь на функцию из одного оператора, возвращающую объект, и написанную в 8 строк)

    function g(id)
    {
    return
      {
      el: document.getElementById(id),
      props: MyProps[id] || []
      }
    }

Типа того) И не, не надо холиваров, я не против, просто мн еэто неудобным кажется.

Comment: @Sh4dow, скажем у меня это больше крик души, заимели уже своим quality... А вообще, я за:

    if(somth) {
        go_somewhere();//...
    }